# How heavy are the folding wingtips of 777x?

Tags: boeing, boeing-777, winglets, weight

To understand the mass penalty that is induced by a folding wingtips, as a first order approximation we can start with just the wingtip's mass without the actuating mechanism.

I could not find the 777x wingtips' mass anywhere. Are they the same as the 747 winglets?